# JavaScript pull data from a form and make sure inputs are true

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a basic HTML5 / JavaScript page. I am stuck at getting the line "var textInput = dataEntry.value;" to pull data from the form. As it sits right now whenever I attempt to input a character it will take any character and I get the message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" can anyone explain to me why I am getting this error?

The code I have now is as follows:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  function validateLetter(dataEntry) {
    try {
      var textInput = dataEntry.value;
      var replacedInput = /[^A-Za-z]/g;
      if (replacedInput.test(textInput) == false)
        throw "You can only enter letters into this field.";
    } catch (textInputError) {
      window.alert(textInputError)
      return false;
    } finally {
      dataEntry.value = form.toLowerCase()
    }
    return true;
  }
  /* ]] */
  < /script>
```

```html
<form action="validateTheCharacters" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="dataEntry">
  <p>Enter your mother's maiden name:
    <input type="text" id="letter1" name="letter1" onkeypress="validateLetter()">
  </p>
  <p>Enter the city you were born in:
    <input type="text" id="letter2" name="letter2" onkeypress="validateLetter()">
  </p>
  <p>Enter the street you grew up on:
    <input type="text" id="letter3" name="letter3" onkeypress="validateLetter()">
  </p>

  <p>Enter your phone number:
    <input type="text" id="number1" name="number1" onkeypress="validateNumber()">
  </p>
  <p>Enter the year you were born:
    <input type="text" id="number2" name="number2" onkeypress="validateNumber()">
  </p>
  <p>Enter the number of siblings you have:
    <input type="text" id="number3" name="number3" onkeypress="validateNumber()">
  </p>

  <p>
    <button type="reset" value="Reset Form">Reset Form</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: You don't pass anything into `validateLetter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dfsq said, you're not passing anything in when you're calling validateLetter(). You need to pass in the current  object. So try this:

onkeypress="validateLetter(this);

Answer (score 0):

You're giving the element as a parameter. Try onkeypress="validateLetter(this)"

Comment: Thank you that helped fix the Error problem I had.